# Elasticsearch NEST API: How to write Query descriptor to implement search with Starts with?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Using Elasticsearch Nest Client to search for company name store in Elasticsearch. Here is sample of my queryExtentions.

I want to change it to make sure when I search for "Starbucks", it should only return record starting with letter "Starbucks". Currently it is rerurning all the records where it has "StarBucks".
Based on documentation, I need to search on "Keyword" filed in order to get the result.
Need sample code to how to achieve this.

****Elastic Search Index Column"

```json
"name": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
        }
    }
}
```

***Code****

```cs
var escapedSearchTerm = ElasticsearchQueryExtensions.EscapeQuery(companyName);
return new QueryContainerDescriptor<SearchResponseStorageContractV1>().Bool(b => b.Must(mu => mu
    .QueryString(qs => qs
        .AllowLeadingWildcard(true)
        .AnalyzeWildcard(true)
        .Fields(f => f.Field(s => s.Company.Name).Field(s => s.Organization.CommonName))
        .Query(escapedSearchTerm)
    )));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Elastic Search Nest Client, but in JSON format you can implement search with functionality using [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html)

Adding a working example with index data,mapping,search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```json
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": "lowercase"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```json
{
    "name":"Starbucks is a American multinational chain of coffeehouses"
}
{
    "name":"coffee at Starbucks"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```json
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "name": {
        "value": "Starbucks",
        "case_insensitive": true    // this param was introduced in 7.10.0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```json
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "67424740",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
      "name": "Starbucks is a American multinational chain of coffeehouses"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: @FlexJogger please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Thanks ESCoder. I am looking for code sample of Nest API to search ES.

Comment: I tried in Kibana Dev tool and it not returning any result.
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "organization.legalEntity.name": {
        "value": "Costco"
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: @FlexJogger which version of elasticsearch are you using? Can you please share your index mapping and some sample index data over which you are performing your query ?